# MVC5 Accessing User in BaseController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am building a mail system where at every page that you land you will get a notification that you have unread mail.

As this needs to be on every page, I thought that I should probably then just add functionality to Base Controller and have the function called that way as every controller I have will be extended of my Base Controller.

As such in my base controller I have the following function which will get me the number of unread invitations this user has:

```
public void GetUnreadInvitationCount(string userId)
{
    var count = Db.Request.Where(r => r.ReceiverId == userId && r.DateLastRead == null).Count();
    if (count > 0) ViewBag.UnreadInvitations = count;
}
```

Then in my constructor I tried the following:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
    public BaseController()
    {
        if (User != null && User.Identity != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            GetUnreadInvitationCount(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the User is null as it has not been instantiated.

How do I get around this?  How do I make a common functionality such as this be on every page and not have to repeat my code on every controller specifically?

I have thought of few solutions myself, but none of these seem to be the right way to go.

Option 1: Create a BaseViewModel which will be called in every page that has this value, this would mean I have to instantiate the method in every action on the website, but at least the code is common for it if I ever need to update it.

Option 2: Do not do this on the server side but setup an ajax script to be called after the page has loaded.  This would have an initial delay but it would work.

Does anyone has a different solution?

**EDIT - For JohnH:**

I have tried solution suggested by john, here is the code:

_Layout.cshtml

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("GetUnreadInvitationCount", "Base");}
```

BaseController.cs

```
public ActionResult GetUnreadInvitationCount()
{
    string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var count = Db.Request.Where(r => r.ReceiverId == userId && r.DateLastRead == null).OrderByDescending(r => r.Id).Count();

    BaseViewModel model = new BaseViewModel {RequestCount = count};

    return View("UnreadInvitations", model);
}
```

UnreadInvitations.cshtml

@model Azularis.System.Events.Models.ViewModels.BaseViewModel

```
@if (@Model.RequestCount > 0)
{
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("Mail", "Index", "Teams", null, new { @class = "mail-image" })
        @Html.ActionLink(@Model.RequestCount.ToString(), "Index", "Teams", null, new { @class = "mail-number" })
    </li>
}
```

However this forces me into a loop where _Layout.cshtml is constantly repeating until the page crashes with

`The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.`

Does anyone knows why it constantly loops?

Comment: `I am building a mail system where at every page that you land you will get a notification that you have unread mail.`  If this looks the same on each page (i.e. the layout is the same), you could actually go a different approach entirely and use something like `@Html.RenderAction("GetUnreadInvitationCount", "Invitation")`, in your `_Layout.cshtml`, where `Invitation` refers to you creating an `InvitationController`, centralising the invitation logic there instead.

Comment: @JohnH I am not familiar with Html.RenderAction method, I'll do some research on it, but if the value returns a 0, how do I go about that then?  As I do not want to show the notification alert if there is no messages.

Comment: `Html.RenderAction()` is just like `Html.Action()`, except that it writes to the output stream directly, rather than returning a string, so it performs a little better.  The action on `InvitationController` would return a view, just like any other controller action typically does, so in that view you could simply do a test for something like: `@if (Model.UnreadMessages.Count > 0) { @* Display notification *@ }`.

Comment: @JohnH I have updated my question with code I applied based on your suggestions.  It causes an infinite loop, would you happen to know why?

Comment: I'm guessing it's hitting the `_Layout.cshtml` file over and over again.  Try this in the `UnreadInvitations.cshtml` view : `@{
    Layout = null;
}`

Comment: @JohnH That has worked and I like your approach.  Can you please post below this as an answer and you can just reuse the code I wrote above so that future visitors understand the solution better and I'll mark it as correct.  Also can you please explain me what Layout = null did and why I had to put that in there in the first place?

Comment: Certainly, I'll do that now, and I'm glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above, the real issue here is not that the code should be shared amongst various controllers, it's that you want a common point in which to run your particular piece of code.  In that sense, it lends itself to being abstracted out into a separate controller, which centralises all invitation logic in one place, leading to better separation of concerns.  You can then invoke those actions either in your `_Layout.cshtml` view, or in any other views if need be.

Using the code in your answer as an example (thanks for that):

InvitationController:

```
public ActionResult GetUnreadInvitationCount()
{
    string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var count = Db.Request.Where(r => r.ReceiverId == userId && r.DateLastRead == null).OrderByDescending(r => r.Id).Count();

    BaseViewModel model = new BaseViewModel {RequestCount = count};

    return View("UnreadInvitations", model);
}
```

InvitationController\UnreadInvitations.cshtml:

```
@if (Model.RequestCount > 0)
{
    // Render whatever you need to display the notification
}
```

Then finally, in your `_Layout.cshtml`, somewhere, you would invoke this action by calling:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("GetUnreadInvitationCount", "Invitation"); }
```

It's important to note that you may need to use `@{ Layout = null; }` in the child view being rendered, otherwise it will default to rendering `_Layout.cshtml` again... which in turn renders the action again... then calls the child view again... and so on. :)  Setting the layout to `null` will prevent that from happening.

*Edit*: Actually, the reason the `_Layout.cshtml` file is being called again is because we're returning a `ViewResult` from the action.  Change that to a `PartialViewResult` and you no longer need the `@{ Layout = null; }`.  Thus:

```
return View("UnreadInvitations", model);
```

becomes:

```
return PartialView("UnreadInvitations", model);
```

Comment: I just read what Alexei wrote, do you feel his is more suitable solution?  At least to me it seems less complicated.

Comment: @Bagzli Personally, I wouldn't go that approach because you don't need to access invitation logic in your base controller - it's not common logic.  It's specific to invitations.  If you start adding methods like this to a central controller, eventually, it becomes a controller that is accessing all manner of different data, which makes it harder to refactor and reuse later on.  Keep things separate and keep them clean, would be my advice. :)

Comment: @Bagzli If you've never come across it before, it would be worth reading about the [Single Responsibility Principal (SRP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), and the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) in general.

Comment: My invitation logic will be access by every page as this will be sitting in the header which is common accross all pages, the idea is, no matter where you are on the website, if you get an invitation, you will see it.

Comment: @Bagzli `as this will be sitting in the header which is common accross all pages` - this is my point.  It's not that all of your controllers need access to that code, it's that the logic needs to render on every page, which isn't the same thing.  So it's not that the logic needs to be accessed by your other controllers, it's that you just need a place to run that code on every page, which is what this approach gives you.

Answer (score 1):

User property is null because it is set after constructor is invoked. However, you do not have to do your logic in the constructor. The following should be placed in your `BaseController`.

```
protected int? GetUserId()
{
    return (User != null && User.Identity != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) ? User.Identity.GetUserId() : null;
}

protected void GetUnreadInvitationCount()
{
    int? userId = GetUserId();
    if (userId == null)
       throw new SecurityException("Not authenticated");

    var count = Db.Request.Where(r => r.ReceiverId == userId.value && r.DateLastRead == null).Count();
    if (count > 0) ViewBag.UnreadInvitations = count;
}
```

`GetUnreadInvitationCount` is called after User is initialized (I guess when some controller action is gets called) and can use `GetUserId` from the `BaseController`.